# Can I use code contracts to work around the inability to have generic constructor constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, code-contracts

I'm tying to write a class that will create immutable copies of another class, and the way I'm doing it requires that the copy takes a date and an instance of the original in the constructor. I know that you can't create a constructor constraint that specifies parameters, but is there a way to work around it using code contracts?

```
public class Copier<o, c>
    where o : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where c : class, c // ideally new(datetime, o)
{
    private Dictionary<DateTime, c> copies;

    public Copier(o original)
    {
        this.copies = new Dictionary<DateTime, c>();
        original.PropertyChanged += 
            this.propertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args);
    }

    private void propertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var original = sender as o;
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        this.copies.Add(now, new c(now, original)); // error here
    }
}
```

The copy clases are created by me, inherit from the originals, override all of the properties to readonly and copy the values from the original in the constructor.

Note: There is a requirement (imposed by me) that the original objects cannot be modified.

Comment: the easy way would be to use new() and an interface with Init(DateTime,T)

Comment: @Guillaume86: I don't think I can do that... I'm shooting for write-once immutability (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) and readonly members can only be set in the ctor.

Comment: "that the original objects cannot be modified." - and yet you implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: immutable objects can return copies with a modified field, for exemple: new T().WithDate(date).WithOriginal(original), each method returns a new T but the first instanciation is useless in that case. Another way (cleaner I think) would be to pass a Func<DateTime,o,C> factory in your Copier constructor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The original objects are mutable and they already implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but their code can't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, pass a creation delegate:

```
public class Copier<o, c>
    where o : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where c : class, c // ideally new(datetime, o)
{
private Dictionary<DateTime, c> copies;
private Func<o, DateTime, c> copyFunc;

public Copier(o original, Func<o, DateTime, c> copyFunc)
{
    this.copyFunc = copyFunc;
    this.copies = new Dictionary<DateTime, c>();
    original.PropertyChanged += 
        this.propertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args);
}

private void propertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var original = sender as o;
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    this.copies.Add(copyFunc(now, original)); 
}
```

}